# Make ElementCollection Set<String> generate surrogate primary key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

[In JPA's CollectionTable example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html)

```
@Entity 
public class Person {
   @Id protected long id;

   @ElementCollection 
   @Column(name="name")
   protected Set<String> nickNames = new HashSet();
}
```

It creates a join table `Person_nickNames` with such values :

[image]

It is hard for edit/delete values . We cannot use tools such as phpmyadmin to click the row and edit the value because there is no PK.

Is it possible for JPA to generate a surrogate primary key in the join table ?

environments : JPA 2 with Hibernate 4.3 implementation

Comment: It's not a join table since it's not joining two other tables. (It's not an entity either, and currently it's primary key is `(Person_id, name)` )

Comment: If you had to worry about the generated table being unsuitable in external environments, then drop the idea of `@CollectionTable` and make it a real `@Entity` with a `@OneToMany` relationship. (It is also not recommended for complex relationships. Target objects cannot be queried, merged and  persisted independently of their parent object. There is obviously no `cascade` option as target objects are always persisted, merged and removed along with their parent).

Comment: The answer is simple. NO

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Smallufo**

Write **`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`** after **`@Id`**

This will make a surrogate primary key.

Comment: in the Person table, yet he wants it in the ElementCollection table (for some reason)

Answer (score -1):

I think that should be possible. Added an ID column as IDENTITY in the PERSON_NICKNAMES table and with the below Person mapping class I am able to generate unique IDs in Person_nicknames table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="Person_Nicknames", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id"))
    @Column(name="name")
    private Set<String> nickNames;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Set<String> getNickNames() {
        return nickNames;
    }
    public void setNickNames(Set<String> nickNames) {
        this.nickNames = nickNames;
    }

}
```

When I save the person and nickname records I see following in person_nicknames table.

```
> ij> select * from Person_nicknames; 
ID         |PERSON_ID  |NAME
1          |6          |nName0
2          |6          |nName1
3          |7          |nName0
4          |7          |nName1
```

Comment: It's weird , the same code doesn't create ID in my environment. I am using MySQL 5.7.10 + SpringDataJPA .

Comment: I tested with Derby DB and see no issues. Will try with MySQL, but need it install it now.

Comment: clearly this is not "with JPA". It is update the database directly.